# Get Customer Address

Tags: magento-1.9, customer, address

I have customer id .

Using customer id i want customer address.

so how to get customer address and using country id how to get full name of country

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Thee address information is stored within the Mage_Customer_Model_Customer so you should be able to create an instance of it with the customer id.

`$customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load($customerId);`

Then depending on the type of address that you are looking for you should be able to call one of the following functions.

**Primary Billing Address:**
`$customer->getPrimaryBillingAddress();`

**Primary Shipping Address:** 
`$customer->getPrimaryShippingAddress();`

**General Address Selection:** `$customer->getAddressItemById();`

As to the country information, by ID do you mean the ISO standard code for the country eg FR, GB etc in which case you could try:

`$countryName = Mage::getModel('directory/country')->load('FR')->getName();
echo $countryName; // Should output France in this example`

Magento Customer Model API Documentation: http://docs.magentocommerce.com/Mage_Customer/Mage_Customer_Model_Customer.html

Comment: Mage::getModel('directory/country')->load('FR') this is not working..

Comment: @ND17 I have updated the example for the country with a little more detail on the process. Hope that helps you.

Comment: How to apply this into magento 2?